# jQuery and scroll animation conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My function works 100% when i only scroll a little bit, but when i scroll all the page down and scroll up fast, my opacity:0 take longer or doesn't work at all. Have any idea why ? It is because my function i call to many times ?

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var TopValue = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (TopValue <= 50) {
        $("div.mouseover > p").css('opacity', 0);
    } else {
        $("div.mouseover > p").animate({
            opacity: '1.0'
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

Comment: Try `$("div.mouseover > p").stop(true,true).css('opacity', 0);`

Answer (score 1):

Since your `function` call is happening multiple times, You have to clear the `animation queue` before starting another `animation`, Please read [.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) for further clarifications.

Try this,

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var TopValue = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (TopValue <= 50) {
        $("div.mouseover > p").css('opacity', 0);
    } else {
        $("div.mouseover > p").stop().animate({
            opacity: '1.0'
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```